# java 8 stream - handle if nothing is found

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

The following stream pipeline does not work if nothing is found, in which case `.findFirst()` throws a NPE.

How can I prevent this?

```
scheduleDurationContainers.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getContainerType() == ScheduleIntervalContainerTypeEnum.BONUS).findFirst().get()
```

Comment: What do you want to do if nothing is found? Have a default value? Throw an exception?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can replace `get()` with `orElse(someDefault)`, which would return some default value if the Optional returned by `findFirst` is empty. Or you can use `orElseThrow(execptionSupplier)` if you want to throw some specific exception when `findFirst` doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to return default value if there is nothing to return using lambda expression then you should use findAny() and orElse() in following sequence

```
Person result1 = persons.stream()                          // Convert to stream
                 .filter(x -> "answer".equals(x.getName()))  // we want to filter "answer" only
                 .findAny()                                // If 'findAny' then return found
                 .orElse(null);                            // If not found, return null
```