# Filter List to get specific object or else return default

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

```java
class Home {
    String homeName;
    String properties;
}
```

```java
List<Home> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Home("DefaultHome","other"));
list.add(new Home("MyHome","other"));
list.add(new Home("BigHome","other"));
```

I want to stream this list to find valid home properties or return `DefaultHome` properties.

So if I do the following, it should return me `DefaultHome` properties.

```
list.stream().filter(a -> a.gethomeName().equals("HomeNotFound")).findFirst();
```

If `"HomeNotFound"` is not in the list, I should get Object of `DefaultHome`
which is `new Home("DefaultHome","other")`

Comment: `.findFirst().orElse(defaultHome)...`

Comment: So are you defining default values or initializing via constructor?  Also `list.add` should be like `list.add(obj)` instead of key value !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java 8 stream - handle if nothing is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470643/java-8-stream-handle-if-nothing-is-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add with an `OR` a second condition to include your default value, sort by name equals `DefaultHome` so that it is allways at the end:

```
list.stream().filter(a -> a.getHomeName().equals("HomeNotFound") || a.getHomeName().equals("DefaultHome"))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(h -> "DefaultHome".equals(h.homeName)))
    .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `findFirst()` returns an Optional result.

You need to use [`Optional.orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) as @Johannes Kuhn has pointed out in the comments:

```
Home home = list.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getHomeName().equals("someName"))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(new Home("DefaultHome","other"));
```

Comment: I need to find the object with name DefaultHome and then return. I can not write constructor like this in orElse

Comment: @KrishnaKumar Firstly, you're confusion *constructor* and *constructor invocation*. `new Home()` - is *constructor invocation* which produces an object. The point is that you need to provide an object of the resulting type as an argument of `orElse()`. **Make sure** that you've checked the [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) before responding to this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to improve on [@Alexander Ivanchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17949945/alexander-ivanchenko)'s answer, but I don't have enough reputation to add comments yet.

Using `orElse` is fine for constant values and variables, but if you pass a constructor directly to `orElse` will call the constructor and instantiate a new object *before the `orElse` method is called*. This is because the arguments to methods are resolved before the methods are called.

Alternatively, one could use `orElseGet`, which takes a `Supplier` function. This function is only called if the `Optional` is empty. So, if we rewrite Alexander's answer as this:

```
Home home = list.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getHomeName().equals("someName"))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseGet(() -> new Home("DefaultHome","other"));
```

, the constructor will only be executed when no match was found in the stream; in other words, only when it is needed.

---

I'd like to add that if you want to search through a list of `House`s efficiently, you should not use a list, but a `Map`:

```
Map<Home> homeMap = new HashMap<>();

homeMap.put("DefaultHome", new Home("DefaultHome","other"));
homeMap.put("MyHome", new Home("MyHome","other"));
homeMap.put("BigHome", new Home("BigHome","other"));

homeMap.getOrDefault("HomeNotFound", new Home("DefaultHome","other"));
```

This code, however, has the same problem as the `Optional.orElse` method: the constructor is called every time, regardless the home is in the map or not. A simple solution for this is to store the default `Home` as a constant:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_HOME = new Home("DefaultHome","other")

Map<Home> homeMap = new HashMap<>();
homeMap.put(DEFAULT_HOME.getHomeName(), DEFAULT_HOME);
homeMap.put("MyHome", new Home("MyHome","other"));
homeMap.put("BigHome", new Home("BigHome","other"));

homeMap.getOrDefault("HomeNotFound", DEFAULT_HOME);
```